# Convert double array to list

Tags: c#, list

txt file that contains several columns of numbers, every column is saved in a double array, what I want to do  is get the average of a specific column, but to do that I have to convert the array to a list and then began to calculate. I have this code so far:

```
  List<double> 1 = new List<double>(NumSepaERG);
  List<double> 12 = NumSepaERG.ToList();
```

But i get and error of Invalid Expression term double

Comment: C# variables must start with alphabetical caracters.

Comment: HI, NumSepaERG is an array that contains a column of data that was read from a .txt file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variable names can't start with a numeric character.  Change to something like:

```
List<double> list1 = new List<double>(NumSepaERG);
```

but you can compute an average using Linq without converting to a list:

```
double average = NumSepaERG.Average();
```

If `NumSepaERG` is a jagged array (an array of arrays), the syntax would be:

```
double average = NumSepaERG[i].Average();
```

where `i` is between 0 and the number of arrays - 1;

Comment: the average method can equally be used in NumSepaERG[0]?

Comment: You stated that `NumSepaERG` is an array of doubles, so `NumSepaERG[0]` would be a single value.  `Average()` only works on arrays and other collection types.

Comment: NumSepaERG[0] contains a column of data, I'm using a variable called counter that adds data to this index.

Comment: So `NumSepaERG` is a jagged array?  Then yes, `Average(NumSepaERG[0])` is valid.  I'll amend my answer.

Comment: i is for loop for each item in this index?

Comment: it could be; I was just illustrating that you could call `Average` on any of the arrays in that jagged array.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a syntax error, you can't have numbers as variable names. You actually don't even need to make it a list.

```
double average = NumSepERG.Average();
```